# Unpack a list inside a list in Django Template

Tags: python, django

How do you unpack a list inside a list within a Django template?

I have a model with two fields named "RecoaterData" and "recoaterTimeStamp". These fields store a list of integers (hopefully this is an appropriate method?). An example of one record would be:

```
RecoaterData = [124,254,366,744,326,743,858,347,734,236,758,533,675,854,58,
               464,447,473,437,996,655,689,644,856,547,235,784,323,]
```

**My goal:**

I want to graph these records over a period of time in my view. So I thought I could query the records I was interested in, then append them into one large list, then access this list in my template. But I can't seem to figure out how to get this into a single list in my template. Instead I am getting a list of lists.

Here is what I see when I run {{recoaters}} in my template:

```
['[528, 277, 672, 324, 621, 195, 820, 209, 146, 462, 635, 829, 153, 480, 
779, 587, 202, 102, 455, 738, 268, 537, 481, 
300, 233, 788, 483, 716, 469, 313]', '[721, 885, 141, 679, 800, 656, 407, 
596, 666, 247, 708, 783, 310, 142, 315,
566, 701, 722, 716, 804, 313, 112, 810, 263, 597, 747, 806]']
```

What I want:

```
[528, 277, 672, 324, 621, 195, 820, 209, 146, 462, 635, 829, 153, 480, 
779, 587, 202, 102, 455, 738, 268, 537, 481, 
300, 233, 788, 483, 716, 469, 313, 721, 885, 141, 679, 800, 656, 407, 
596, 666, 247, 708, 783, 310, 142, 315,
566, 701, 722, 716, 804, 313, 112, 810, 263, 597, 747, 806]
```

**views.py**

```
class recoaterDataListView(LoginRequiredMixin,ListView):
    model = Data
    template_name = 'charts.html'
    login_url = 'login'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        query = Data.objects.filter(author_id = self.kwargs ["author"], ProcessIdentifier_data=self.kwargs['pi'])
        Recoaters = []
        TimeStamps = []
        for data in query:
            Recoaters.append(data.RecoaterData)
            TimeStamps.append(data.recoaterTimeStamp)
        context['recoaters'] = Recoaters
        context['timestamps'] = TimeStamps
        return context
```

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of [naming convention](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#naming-conventions), you should set the variable names to `recoaters` and `timestamps`:

```
    recoaters = []
    timestamps = []
    for data in query:
        recoaters.append(data.RecoaterData)
        timestamps.append(data.recoaterTimeStamp)
    context['recoaterdata'] = recoaters
    context['timedata'] = timestamps
```

In your template, if I understand correctly, maybe you want to show each element in the list timestamps using this:

```
{% for each_timestamp in timestamps %}
    {{ each_timestamp }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Unless you're differentiating between lists and tuples for some reason, if you're going to suggest renaming, I think it'd make more sense to go with `recoaters` instead of `recoater_list`.

Comment: Yeah you're right, `recoaters` actually makes more sense in this case

Answer (score 0):

If a value is an iterable in a Django template, you can iterate over it, regardless of whether it's a member of another iterable. Just put your queryset straight into the context and use that.

```
context['recoaters'] = Data.objects.filter(
    # ...
)
```

You can walk through them this way without having to build a new list and without losing the data relationships.

```
{% for recoater in recoaters %}
    ...
    {% for timestamp in recoater.recoaterTimeStamp.all %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

If what you're saying is mostly accurate, `recoater.recoaterTimeStamp` seems to be either a many-to-many relation or a reverse reference from a foreign key. In either case, this should work. If that's not the case, then something else is going on here, and it's not clear what that would be without seeing your models.

Comment: Thanks for the help here guys, I edited my post to hopefully be more clear about what I am trying to achieve. I still can't seem to get the list to come through in my template as one list....Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

The lists stored in the database are actually stored as strings. So I had to convert them to a list first, then concatenate the lists together to get a single list. This worked:

```
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        query = Data.objects.filter(author_id = self.kwargs ["author"], ProcessIdentifier_data=self.kwargs['pi'])
        Recoaters = []
        TimeStamps = []
        for data in query:
            Recoaterstring = ast.literal_eval(data.RecoaterData)
            Recoaters = Recoaters+Recoaterstring
            timestampString = ast.literal_eval(data.RecoaterData)
            TimeStamps = TimeStamps+timestampString
        context['recoaters'] = Recoaters
        context['times'] = TimeStamps
        return context
```